# Assign values to Textbox from datasource in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have one aspx page. I have assign only one textbox in that page. I have retrived the records from the database. Now i want to assign the values to the textbox without writing the code in aspx.cs:

```
Texbox1.Text=ds.tables[0].rows["Name"].toString();
```

But the value has to be assign to that Textbox.
How can i achive it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Wrap your texbox and other controls in a FormView control, bind the formview control to the datasource and use <aspx:TextBox runat="server" Text='<#% Eval("Name")' />